# How to prove Kleene star to be uncounably infinite?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

I have the language $L = \{a, b\}$. How can I prove that the Kleene star (set of all words over the language) of this language is uncountably infinite or countably infinite?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What do you know about cardinalities? **Hint:** express $L^*$ as a union of countably many finite sets.

Comment: A set x  is finite if there is bijection from natural numbers to x. So L* can be as big as it wants but each of the words in L∗ is finite. So, L* doesn't have enough elements to give each natural number, which are not countable, a representation.

Comment: does this have something to do with the cantors theorem.

Comment: A set $X$ is finite if it has a finite number of elements. What you've said is the definition of a countable set. No, it has nothing with this theorem. $L^*$ is a set of all finite-length words over $L$. But there are only countably many values for word lengths: words of length 1, words of length 2, etc. And there are finite number of words of a fixed length.

Comment: @user2698566, your suggestion is flawed. Each natural number is finite as well, yet there are countably infinite natural numbers. It's very possible (and indeed the case for `L*`) that a language with only finite strings has infinite cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L = \{a, b\}$. Denote by $L_k$ the set of all words of length $k$ over $L$.

> **Proposition 1:** $|L_k| = 2^k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$

*Proof.* Induction by $k$. For $k = 0$ (or $k = 1$) it is obvious. Fix some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume that the proposition holds for all $k \leq n$. Any word $w \in L_{n + 1}$ can be uniquely written as the concatenation of some word $v \in L_n$ and a letter $c \in L$, i.e. $w = vc$. And conversely each word $v \in L_n$ "generates" two different words $va$ and $vb$  from $L_{n+1}$. Hence $|L_{n+1}| = 2|L_n| = 2^{n+1}.$

> **Proposition 2:** $L^* = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}L_i.$

*Proof.* Definition of $L^*$.

From these propositions it follows that $L^*$ is a countable union of finite sets which is a countable set itself (roughly, you can enumerate each $L_k$ consequently and each $L_k$ will be enumerated after finite number of steps).

Answer (score 2):

Choose $a$ to be the digit $1$ and $b$ to be the digit $0$.

Consider a string from the language $S$, and prepend a $1$ to it.  For example, $\text{babba}$ becomes $1\underbrace{01001}_\text{babba}$.  That is a unique integer in binary.

It should be obvious (if you are familiar with binary) how to convert between strings in your language and $\mathbb Z^{+}$.  So the language is countable.